# how to do prefix and suffix search on full text indexed table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How to query a full text table like "like" operator? Suffix search is not fetching the result... i am using contains and searching in all the columns.Can you please help , how to do suffix search on full text indexed table

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 8):

You can perform a prefix search using the wildcard operator:

```
SELECT Description, ProductDescriptionID
FROM Production.ProductDescription
WHERE CONTAINS (Description, ' "top*" ' );
```

([Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142492%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))

Suffix searches are not supported. You have to do a hack like keep a copy of the reversed text as shown [here](http://www.sqlhelpline.com/2009/05/search-suffix-using-full-text-search-in.html).

Comment: This was super helpful!  Just reversing the string didn't even occur to me, but I'm going to try this out.